# Find all html elements whose contains a specific class

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want `BeautifulSoup` to find all element in html page whose have a certain class. But they can also have extra classes. For example:

```
soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'super_class1'})
```

This code only finds `tr` whose have only `super_class1`. But I want it to find all `tr` whose  contains this class such

```
<tr class='super_class1'>aaa</tr>
```

and

```
<tr class='super_class1 super_class2'>bbb</tr>
```

and

```
<tr class='super_class1 super_class15  super_class16'>ccc</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed (https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/410304); the problem is basically that the soup doesn't recognizes spaces in class name.

But if you have to use a version without the fix, the above link also provides a solution:

```
soup.findAll(True, {'class': re.compile(r'\bsuper_class1\b')})
```